# App crashes when loading image from url in Cache Network Image

Tags: flutter, dart

I have implemented a listview and I'm getting images from an Api, which returns image urls.

I have used Cached Network Image for showing images in listview, but when app starts it loads 2 3 images and then app crash. Message shows:

> App terminates due to memory crash

I have tried another plugins for this, and tried to show fewer images at a time.

```
//  This code is for showing images in listview

***class Album extends StatelessWidget {
          final String galleryId;

          Album(this.galleryId);

          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                    centerTitle: true,
                    title: Text("ALBUM"),
                    leading: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.keyboard_arrow_left,
                          size: 35.0,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        })),
                body: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: AlbumListWidget(galleryId),
                ));
          }
        }

        class AlbumListWidget extends StatelessWidget {
          final String galleryId;
          final repo = AlbumRepo();

          AlbumListWidget(this.galleryId);

          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Flexible(
                  child: PagewiseGridView<String>.count(
                    pageSize: 16,
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 8,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 8,
                    itemBuilder: (context, entry, index, items) {
                      return InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            final viewer = ImageViewerWidget(items, index);
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) =>
                                    viewer));
                          },
                          child: AlbumItemWidget(entry));
                    },
                    pageFuture: (pageIndex, currentSize) {
                      return repo.getSchools(pageIndex, galleryId);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );

        }


     //   This is AlbumItemWidget Class

        class AlbumItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
          final String image;

          AlbumItemWidget(this.image);

          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return CachedNetworkImage(
              imageUrl: image,
```

Comment: What's the stacktrace?

Comment: When I run the app and go to screen images are loading from url . I have implemented Page Grid view for listing Its starts showing 2 3 images then stack shows app terminates due to memory issue